# Java: How does the == operator work when comparing int?

Tags: java

Given this Java code:

```
int fst = 5;
int snd = 6;

if(fst == snd)
    do something;
```

I want to know how Java will compare equality for this case. Will it use an XOR operation to check equality?

Comment: No, it will perform a `if_icmpeq` JVM bytecode instruction.

Comment: @jsn That sounds like a good answer to me (well, perhaps ever so slightly expanded).

Comment: The `==` operation translates to the `if_icmpeq` instruction in bytecode; during execution, this pops off the object references from the operand stack and compares them.

Comment: I also want to add that (and I know you didn't ask this) if you compare Integers (capital I, spelled out), which are objects to eachother using ==, that compares whether they're the same instance instead of whether the value of the two Integers are the same. So you should use .equals for those.

Comment: `if_icmpeq` pops the top two `ints` off the stack and compares them. If the two integers are equal, execution branches to the address (`pc` + `branchoffset`), where pc is the address of the `if_icmpeq` opcode in the bytecode and `branchoffset` is a 16-bit signed integer parameter following the `if_icmpeq` opcode in the bytecode. If the integers are not equal, execution continues at the next instruction.

Comment: Of course, if you're comparing object references `if_acmpeq` will be used instead.  And you can't compare floats and doubles for equal, but there are separate greater-than/less-than compare ops for them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you asking "what native machine code does this turn into?"?  If so, the answer is "implementation-depdendent".

However, if you want to know what [JVM bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) is used, just take a look at the resulting .class file (use e.g. [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) to disassemble it).

Comment: +1 Absolutely! If one does not leave a decision like "how to implement `int` equality" up to the writers of JVM, he/she might as well write the JVM for them :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found what I require.

Comment: It is worthwhile to add that you can see even the native code that the JIT compiler produces. There you'll finally be able to witness your XOR or CMP or whatever the `==` happens to turn into.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are asking about the JVM, use the `javap` program.

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 5;
        System.out.println(5 == a);

    }

}
```

Here is the disassembly:

```
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_5
       1: istore_1
       2: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       5: iconst_5
       6: iload_1
       7: if_icmpne     14
      10: iconst_1
      11: goto          15
      14: iconst_0
      15: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
      18: return
}
```

In this case it optimized the branching a bit and used `if_icmpne`. In most cases, it will use `if_icmpne` or `if_icmpeq`.

`if_icmpeq` : `if ints are equal, branch to instruction at branchoffset (signed short constructed from unsigned bytes branchbyte1 << 8 + branchbyte2)`

`if_icmpn` : `if ints are not equal, branch to instruction at branchoffset (signed short constructed from unsigned bytes branchbyte1 << 8 + branchbyte2)`